# NSMutableArray With UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having an issue with my `UITableviewCell`, it generates only the first index inside of my `NSMutableArray`. I've used  NSLog(@"Count %i %@", [enterPrise_names count], enterPrise_names);
To check the number of objects inside of my `NSMutableArray` everything seems fine with that.
I've already wired up everything including the `UItableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelege`, and Matching up the cell identifier of the TableViewCell.

The problem is that two of my labels only show the first object inside of my `NSMutableArrays`.
I want to post the photos of my simulation to you guys but this is my first post of Stackoverflow and I don't have enough reputation to do that task.

well it looks like this

Fuji  Siam

Fuji  Siam

Fuji  Siam

Fuji  Siam

Fuji  Siam

Fuji  Siam

Here is my code

```
#import "MyQueueViewController.h"
#import "QueueCell.h"
@interface MyQueueViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyQueueViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


     enterPrise_names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Fuji",@"MK",@"KFC",@"PizzaHut",@"McDonal",@"BurgerKing", nil];
    BranchName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Siam",@"Paragon", @"CTW", @"Pinklao", @"Bangkae", @"Bangna", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [enterPrise_names count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"QueueCell";
    QueueCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[QueueCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    }
    NSLog(@"Count %i %@", [enterPrise_names count], enterPrise_names);
    cell.txtBranch.text = [BranchName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.txtShop.text = [enterPrise_names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I would be very appreciated if any of you guys would point out my mistakes. 
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tableview contains many sections but but only one row by section. Try this :

```
cell.txtBranch.text = [BranchName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.txtShop.text = [enterPrise_names objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

However, if you don't actually need many sections, you should probably set the number of rows according  to your array and inverse numbers of rows and sections in here :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [enterPrise_names count];
}
```

Comment: Yeahhhhh it works !!! 
Thank you very much I overlooked that 
Very appreciated Justafinger, you are the best !

Comment: Do you know how can I close this issue ? Since I already got the solution. I'm very new here.

Comment: You don't actually close issues, you just accept answers. In case other people have the same problem they'll be able to see what solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try,
Change `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ....
    NSLog(@"Count %i %@", [enterPrise_names count], enterPrise_names);
    cell.txtBranch.text = [BranchName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.txtShop.text = [enterPrise_names objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    return cell;
}
```

Since each section has one row, `indexPath.row` will be `zero` in all case. So only first element of both `BranchName` and `enterPrise_names` array will be shown in labels. Changing `indexPath.row` to `indexPath.section` will solve the problem

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I overlooked this point 
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [enterPrise_names count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}
if I just swap the return values of these two then my code will work just fine. ^^ 
Thank you again

Comment: @user3027109 Yes, you are correct. Changing it will solve the issue